# Plot three different columns on y axis using python

Tags: python, seaborn, line-plot

I'm trying to do a line plot with one line per column. My dataset looks like this:

[image]

I'm using this code, but it's giving me the following error:
*ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 27*

```
plot_x = 'bill__effective_due_date'
plot_y = ['RR_bucket1_perc', 'RR_bucket7_perc', 'RR_bucket14_perc']

ax = sns.pointplot(x=plot_x, y=plot_y, data=df_rollrates_plot, marker="o", palette=sns.color_palette("coolwarm"))

display(ax.figure)
```

Maybe it's a silly question but I'm new to python so I'm not sure how to do this. This is my expected output:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems you are looking for [`sns.lineplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

Comment: If you don't mind not using seaborn, in Pandas it is as easy as: `df_rollrates_plot.plot(x = plot_x, y = plot_y)`. Also, make sure that you have parsed the dates as dates (when reading the table, use the `parse_dates="bill__effective_due_date"` option in `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot the dataframe as follows (edit: I updated the code below to make `bill__effective_due_date` the index of the dataframe):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

rr1 = [20,10,2,10,2,5]
rr7 = [17,8,2,8,2,4]
rr14 = [12,5,2,5,2,3]
x = ['Nov-1','Nov2','Nov-3','Nov-4','Nov-5','Nov-6']

df_rollrates_plot = pd.DataFrame({'RR_bucket1_perc':rr1, 
                                  'RR_bucket7_perc':rr7, 
                                  'RR_bucket14_perc':rr14})

df_rollrates_plot.index = x
df_rollrates_plot.index.name = 'bill__effective_due_date'

sns.lineplot(data=df_rollrates_plot)
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the wrong shape to take advantage of the `hue` parameter in seaborn's lineplot.  You need to stack it so that the columns become categorical values.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
rr1 = [20,10,2,10,2,5]
rr7 = [17,8,2,8,2,4]
rr14 = [12,5,2,5,2,3]
x = ['Nov-1','Nov2','Nov-3','Nov-4','Nov-5','Nov-6']

df = pd.DataFrame({'bill_effective_due_date':x,
                                  'RR_bucket1_perc':rr1, 
                                  'RR_bucket7_perc':rr7, 
                                  'RR_bucket14_perc':rr14})

# This is where you are reshaping your data to make it work like you want
df = df.set_index('bill_effective_due_date').stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['bill_effective_due_date','roll_rates_perc','roll_rates']

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='bill_effective_due_date',y='roll_rates', hue='roll_rates_perc', marker='o')
```

[image]